# HTML Form method vs jQuery function type

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm totally a newbie on frontend development and just learning about jQuery.

I'm confused about "submit a HTML form with jQuery ajax". Here is a simple example:

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" >
    <textarea name="text" id="message" placeholder="Write something to us"> </textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="return formSubmit();" value="Send">
</form>

<script>
    function formSubmit(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&message=' + message;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            type: "PUT",
            success: function(data){
                $("#myForm").html(data);
            },
            error: function (){}
        });
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

As you see, when we click the button `Send`, the function `formSubmit()` will be invoked and the jQuery.ajax will do its job. It will send a http request with the type `PUT`.

But there is an attribute in the HTML form `method="post"`, now I'm confused. When we click the button, what will actually happen? The jQuery.ajax will send a request in the js function but what will the `method="post"` do? Or `method="post"` can be ignored? If it does nothing, can we make the attribute `method` empty: `<form class="form" action="" method="">`?

**Additional**

Now I realise that the type of the buttion in this example is `button`, instead of `submit`. If I change the type into `submit` and click it, what will happen? Will it send two http requests, a post request comes from the form and a put request comes from the jQuery.ajax?

Comment: actually if you use jquery ajax you can remove the <form xxxxxx > and </form>  from your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is badly designed and confusing.

The `formSubmit` function will only be called when the button is clicked. When the button is clicked, that function will run, and *nothing else* will happen; since the input is not a submit button, the form will not attempt to submit. All network activity will result from the `jQuery.ajax` inside the function. In this case, the `<form>` and the `method="post"` are ignored completely, since the form doesn't get submitted - the method used will be the one in the `.ajax` function, which is PUT.

But the form is still submittable, if the user presses enter while focused inside the `<input type="text"`. If they do that, then the `formSubmit` function will not be called (since the button wasn't clicked), and the user's browser will send the `name` and the `message` as form data to the server, on the current page - and yes, as a POST. (Is the current page this code is on `submit.php`? If not, that may be a mistake. Perhaps the person who wrote the code completely overlooked the possibility of the form being submitable without using the button.)

To make the example less confusing, I'd change the button to a *submit* button, and add a submit handler to the form instead of a click listener to the button. Then have the submit handler `return false` or call `e.preventDefault` so that all network activity goes through the `.ajax` call.

Comment: `form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => { e.preventDefault()` or `form.addEventListener('submit', () => { /* stuff */ return false; });`

Comment: Given your current code, if you change it to a submit button, the form will attempt to submit when the button is clicked. But `formSubmit` will also run.

Answer (score 0):

The `method` attribute in HTML Form is used to send the form data when you're sending it without the help of an Ajax Request or any other scripting language.

When you use a scripting language like JS and Jquery, you have the chance to send the data via an AJAX request. Inside the AJAX request, you can define the method again. So, it won't rely on the HTML Form's `method` attribute.

Few resources you can follow:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

The form tag gives support by giving several inbuilt default actions, but since you have defined a submit button and made a function to be executed onclick manually, so the form tag will only confuse the structure. So it's better to remove the form tag completely and you code will look like

```
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" >
    <textarea name="text" id="message" placeholder="Write something to us"> </textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="return formSubmit();" value="Send">


<script>
    function formSubmit(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&message=' + message;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            type: "PUT",
            success: function(data){
                $("#myForm").html(data);
            },
            error: function (){}
        });
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `method` and `action` tags are useful when you are not using any ajax request.

➡️ Suppose you are not using the `ajax` request then what will happen?

1. Since your `method` is `POST` it'll append the form-data inside the body of the HTTP request.
2. Then the form-data is sent to the page specified in the `action` attribute.

But since you are now controlling the form submission manually through `ajax`. You can skip those `attributes`. On that case you can specify on your `formSubmit` method what to do when your submission is completed.

You can also prevent the `form` submission using `preventDefault`.
For example:

```
<form onSubmit="formSubmit(event);">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>

function formSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Now you can set where to go when your form is submitted successfully.
}
```